# Upload videos more than 50mb on telegram bot using python

Tags: python, video, upload, bots, telegram

I can only upload videos upto 50mb.
But many bots on telegram can send videos upto 2gb.
So,I need a Python code to upload large videos on telegram bot.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to develop the bot yourself and secondly you can use [pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/) it uses [Mtproto](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/issues/514) which can help you bypass the 50MB limit.

Here's Some Dummy code from pyrogram

```
## Send video by uploading from local file
await app.send_video("me", "video.mp4")

## Add caption to the video
await app.send_video("me", "video.mp4", caption="video caption")

## Send self-destructing video
await app.send_video("me", "video.mp4", ttl_seconds=10)

## Keep track of the progress while uploading
async def progress(current, total):
    print(f"{current * 100 / total:.1f}%")

await app.send_video("me", "video.mp4", progress=progress)
```

As pyrogram is asynchronous library you need to be a little familiar with [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. 
Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. 
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).